# Input String Was Not In A Correct Format. int.Parse(array[0]);

Tags: c#

Im pretty new to C# and using an open source code that connects to the website and trades items.

My previous question was very stupid and Im very sorry!

I found where the code stops and need suggestions on how to fix the error. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGO8V.png

I also tagged where I think the error is with //Code stops on this line!

```
namespace BOT
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private const string serverName = "http://MYVPSIP/ezyskins.php";
        private const string serverDemon = "ws://MYVPSIP:5555";

        public static List<IWebSocketConnection> allsockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
        public static WebSocketServer server = new WebSocketServer(serverDemon);
        public static WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        public static GameJson GJ = new GameJson();
        public static List<DepositItem> DI = new List<DepositItem>();
        public static List<DepositUser> DU = new List<DepositUser>();
        public static Thread ResolveSocketsThread;
        public static Thread GameThread;
        public static Thread TradeBotThread;
        public static Thread SendBotThread;
        public static Thread SteamAuth;
        public static Thread ClearInfo;
        public static int globalGameID = 0;
        public static string winnersecretkey;
        public static List<string> FoundPrices = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> resTrades = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> waitTrades = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> BannedSteamID = new List<string>();
        public static object steamRequest = new object();
        public static object lockSocket = new object();
        public static string username = ""; //Bot Login
        public static string password = ""; //Bot Pass
        public static string steamID = ""; //Steam64 ID
        public static string sessionID = ""; //Cookies
        public static string steamLogin = ""; //Cookies
        public static string steamLoginSecure = ""; //Cookies
        public static string machineAuth = ""; //Cookies
        public static string steamApiKey = ""; //Bots Api
        public static string webServerSecretKey = ""; Secret Key
        public static int gameID = 0;
        public static double gameKey = 0.0;
        public static int totalItems = 0;
        public static double totalPrice = 0.0;
        public static double totalPrice2 = 0.0;
        public static long closeAt = 0L;
        public static long openAt = 0L;
        public static double last_ticket = 0.0;
        public static string hash = string.Empty;
        public static DepositUser winner;
        public static string totalwinner;
        public static bool deposits = false;
        public static bool timerStarted = false;
        public static bool gameStarted = false;
        public static NumberFormatInfo nfi = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string source = string.Empty;
                using (HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest())
                {
                    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
                    httpRequest.Cookies = new CookieDictionary(false) {
                        {
                            "key", webServerSecretKey
                        }
                    };
                    requestParams["method"] = "getinfo";
                    source = httpRequest.Post(serverName, requestParams, false).ToString();
                }
                string[] array = Program.explode("(|)", source);
                Program.globalGameID = int.Parse(array[0]); //Code stops on this line!
                Program.winnersecretkey = array[1];
                Program.server.SupportedSubProtocols = new string[] {
                    "ezyskins"
                };
                Program.ResolveSocketsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.ResolveSockets));
                Program.GameThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.Game));
                Program.TradeBotThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.TradeBot));
                Program.SendBotThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.SendBotT));
                Program.SteamAuth = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.SteamAuthT));
                Program.ClearInfo = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.ClearInfoT));
                Program.GameThread.IsBackground = true;
                Program.TradeBotThread.IsBackground = true;
                Program.ResolveSocketsThread.IsBackground = true;
                Program.SendBotThread.IsBackground = true;
                Program.SteamAuth.IsBackground = true;
                Program.ClearInfo.IsBackground = true;
                Program.ResolveSocketsThread.Start();
                Program.GameThread.Start();
                Program.TradeBotThread.Start();
                Program.SendBotThread.Start();
                Program.SteamAuth.Start();
                Program.ClearInfo.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    string a = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (a == "clear")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                    if (a == "save-online")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sockets: " + Program.allsockets.Count<IWebSocketConnection>());
                        foreach (IWebSocketConnection current in Program.allsockets)
                        {
                            string text = "";
                            if (File.Exists("online.txt"))
                            {
                                text = File.ReadAllText("online.txt");
                            }
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> current2 in current.ConnectionInfo.Headers)
                            {
                                File.WriteAllText("online.txt", string.Concat(new object[] {
                                    text, "\r\n", current.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress, ":", current.ConnectionInfo.ClientPort, " (", current2.Key, ": ", current2.Value, ")"
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (a == "restart")
                    {
                        Program.ResolveSocketsThread.Abort();
                        Program.ResolveSocketsThread.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  // ----> This gets printed out! <----
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked what source contains ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving valid integer value to `int.Parse` because of that you receive this exception. In this case you can't use `int.TryParse` because you need your game ID. What I advice you is to debug your code and see what are the value of array.

You need to add this lines if you want to see it in the console.

```
foreach(string sArr in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sArr);
}
```

After that see on which position is your game ID and put it in the int.Parse.

Comment: Thank you! The error was so simple. My config mysql file had wrong ip. OMG 5 HOURS SPENT TO REALISE THAT!

Comment: Search a tutorial for debug in C# next time, it will save you hours in the future if you want to continue with the coding. Mark one of the answers for correct and move on and good luck

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate what's in the inside of the array. If value if cannot be parsed into number, exception will be thrown.

Print the array into the debug console or set break point to parsing line and add array into watch if you're using visual studio.

Comment: Thank you! The error was so simple. My config mysql file had wrong ip. OMG 5 HOURS SPENT TO REALISE THAT!